# Proof of Theorem II, 7.11 in "Residues and duality"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, sheaf-theory, schemes, injective-module

When reading the proof of Theorem II, 7.11 in "Residues and Duality" by R. Hartshorne, I have encountered some steps that are unclear to me.

1.Firstly, I am unsure about the notation $\mathscr{O}_Z$ mentioned on the third line of page 129. Could you please clarify its meaning? (As  Aphelli commented, it is the extension by zero of the structure sheaf of the integral subscheme $Z\subset X$.)

2.Additionally, I would appreciate further explanation on how to deduce that the image of $\phi$ has support in $Z'$ as stated on the seventh line of page 129.

3. How can we shrink $U$ so that $\psi$ is injective on $U$?

Any comments or insights on these matters would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without having an access to the book, how can we help you ?

Comment: I don't think it'll be an easy task to find a tougher, hard-to-understand author in some advanced, highly complex topic in mathematics than Hartshorne. Even his classic "Algebraic Geometry" is really, *really* hard to understand and it is thus many times recommended only as a consult book for people who already know something about that theme. Add to this that "Residues and Duality" was written based on some notes by Grothendieck and the book is printed in an ancient typing form of mathematics which isn't very friendly to readers, and you have a rather tough book to tackle...

Comment: @DonAntonio this is unnecessarily pessimistic and contains many statements that do not match the lived reality of many mathematicians I know. Why post this?

Comment: To the OP: without posting more content from the proof you're looking for help on, it's going to be tough for your question to get traction here - at MSE, we prefer if a question can be self-contained, if possible. Please add details to your post with an [edit].

Comment: @KReiser: Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @KReiser Because I wouldn't want anybody trying to read Hartshorne to go nuts and feel dissapointed with him(her)self, and it matches the lived reality of *any* mathematician I know. In the best of cases one lecturer once told me that Hartshorne's AG "could" be a good consult book in some cases for graduate students. I know several other books much better for introducting students to algebraic geometry, but it is a matter of taste, I believe.

Comment: Dear @DonAntonio, Thanks for your kindness. Indeed, I feel disappointed with myself as I fail to comprehend this proof. Even so, this book is the only reference I know which classifies injective modules on locally noetherian schemes.

Comment: $O_Z$ could be the structure sheaf of the integral subscheme structure on the closed subset $\overline{\{x\}}$ of $X$.

Comment: The image of $\varphi$ has support contained in $Supp(I) \cap Z$. Now, $x’$ is a generic (what Hartshorne calls maximal) point of this locally Noetherian scheme, so $Z’$ is a neighborhood of $x’$. I understand that the precise domain of $\varphi$ isn’t important (Hartshorne reduces it over the course of the proof), so maybe this is enough to complete the proof?

Comment: Dear @Aphelli, Thank you for your comments. The problem is that, on p.133, -4 line in the proof of Thm. 7.18, a similar notation $O_{Z'}$ means the ideal sheaf corresponding to the closed immersion $Z'\to X$. Thus, I don't know which one the author is using on p.129.

Comment: Does there exist a natural map from the ideal sheaf of $Z$ into $J(x)$ (whatever $J(x)$ is, if $Z=\overline{\{x\}}$)? If so, then that’s indeed what $O_Z$ should be (the remark that the support had to be contained in $Z$ is unimportant in my previous comment).

Comment: Dear @Aphelli, No, I don't think there is a natural map from the ideal sheaf of $Z$ into $J(x)$. Presently, I guess the notation $O_Z$ on p.129 is what you said and the  $O_{Z'}$ on p.133 is the ideal sheaf. It may be an unconscious confusion of notation.

Comment: @Aphelli, Sorry, but I didn't understand your argument concerning the support.

Comment: What didn’t you understand? I’m just claiming that $Z’$ is, in $Supp(I) \cap Z$ (hence the support of the image of $\varphi$), a neighborhood of $x’$. It might be sufficient for what Hartshorne does afterwards (since he shrinks the domain several times).

Comment: Dear @Aphelli, When you write "The image of $\varphi$  has support contained in $()\cap $. Now, $x′$ is a generic  point of this locally Noetherian SCHEME", you are talking about which scheme? For example, is $Supp(I)$ locally closed in $X$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my lack of precision. The support of the image of $\varphi$ (let’s call it $P$) is certainly a closed subspace of $Z$; it contains $x’$ (hence $Z’$), and it is contained in $Supp(I)$.  Since $x’$ is maximal in $Supp(I)$, $P$ contains no point of $Z$ that specializes to $x’$, so that $Z’$ is a neighborhood of $x’$ in $P$.

Comment: Dear @Aphelli, In fact, even the existence of a maximal point of $Supp(I)$ is not clear to me.

Comment: This is asserted earlier in the proof, though (why didn’t you write it in the first place?). I think it’s a completely formal fact – because there are no infinite sequences $x_n$ in $X$ such that $x_n$ is a specialization of $x_{n+1}$, because $X$ is locally Noetherian.

Comment: Dear @Aphelli, You are right. Sorry for that and thanks again.